# using drag event to morph shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm new to raphael and am creating an animation. A diamond that can morph to an upper or lower triangle. There are five points in the animation an I can cycle through using click events. What I want is to be able to use the mouse so that in one drag the animation can move from any one point to any another. Does anyone have any ideas how to implement this?

This is my html:

```
<body>
  <div id='paper1'></div>
  <div class='animate'>
    <p>Animate!</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

And my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = 0;
  var paper = Raphael('paper1', 500, 500); 
  var p1 = paper.path("M200,200 L 250,230 L 300,200 L250,170 Z")
  p1.attr({"stroke-width": 4, fill: "red"});

  $('.animate').click(function(){
     morph(p1,x);
     x ++;
     if (x === 8) x = 0;
  });
});

var morph = function(shape, count){
  console.log(count);
  if (count === 0) path =      {path:"M200,200 L250,200 L300,200 L250,90 Z"};
  else if (count === 1) path = {path:"M200,200 L250,200 L300,200 L250,10 Z"};
  else if (count === 2) path = {path:"M200,200 L250,200 L300,200 L250,90 Z"};
  else if (count === 3) path = {path:"M200,200 L250,230 L300,200 L250,170 Z"};
  else if (count === 4) path = {path:"M200,200 L250,310 L300,200 L250,200 Z"};
  else if (count === 5) path = {path:"M200,200 L250,390 L300,200 L250,200 Z"};
  else if (count === 6) path = {path:"M200,200 L250,310 L300,200 L250,200 Z"};
  else if (count === 7) path = {path:"M200,200 L 250,230 L 300,200 L250,170 Z"};


  shape.animate(path,300);
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

C

Answer (score 0):

Solved this after some playing around. This is my solution if anyone's interested.
https://github.com/cmcguire79/raphael-widget